# Android-x86 on Oracle VirtualBox - error

Tags: virtualbox, android-x86

I'm trying to install android-x86-5.1-rc1.iso (from http://www.android-x86.org/) in the virtualbox v5.0.14 and this is what I get.

[image]

[image]

The screen freezes there and nothing else happens. Does anybody knows to to make it work?

Edit: added screenshot:
[image]
*CPU is an i7 x64. OS: Windows 10 x64.*

Comment: We need way more detail. What are the settings that you gave the VM? Maybe try deleting the VM and try to follow these [instructions](http://www.keyables.com/2015/10/how-to-run-android-x86-51-lollipop-with.html). By doing this we can at least ensure that your VM settings are correct.

Comment: As per the snapshot , unsupported CPU, did you make sure that Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: I did exactly as indicated on http://www.keyables.com/2015/10/how-to-run-android-x86-51-lollipop-with.html

Comment: @Scorpion99 Perfect! you solved. post as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Hardware Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS.
Usually it is disabled by default.
VMware and VirtualBox cannot run virtual machines without enabling it.